# Factory geojson Mapbox FeatureCollection not loading Polygons

Tags: php, jquery, mapbox, geojson, polygons

I have a geojson polygon FeatureCollection generated / json_encode with PHP, stored / parsed in Jquery. Everything is happy, no errors, geojsonLint didn't have a problem with it, except the polygons won't actually load on my map.

Markers from the same featurecollection load fine, and console.log on both the geojson object and the geo object have coordinates and seem happy.

The geojson is stored in UTF-8 and has foreign language accents and escaped single quotes.

The key lines of code are:

```
//PHP
$MapPoly = str_replace("'", "\'", json_encode($db['MapPoly'],JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));

//JQuery
var geojson = <?=$MapPoly?>;
if(geojson){
    geojson = $.parseJSON(geojson);

    //tried both of these methods w/ v2.2.3/mapbox.js
    var geo = L.mapbox.featureLayer(geojson).addTo(map);

    //not at the same time, of couse

    var geo = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
    geo.setGeoJSON(geojson);
}
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated,...this one has officially got me stumped.

Comment: Is this how the code actually looks? I mean, it's not two separate files / there's nothing else separating them?

Comment: Yes, same file, a couple line of script boundaries and initializing the map, 7-8 lines away from each other.

Comment: try with:$MapPoly =$db['MapPoly'];

//JQuery
var geojson = <? echo json_encode($MapPoly);?>;

Answer (score 0):

you need to `echo` it to get the php data in `javascript/jquery/html`:

```
var geojson = <?php echo $MapPoly?>;
```

avoid using short tag.

Comment: No change,...the same object on the other side. I also tried without my apostrophe and accented characters in intitial the geojson string, removed the str_replace and JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK. No dice.

Comment: @MichaelClark do `console.log(geojson)` and see.or post a sample `$db['MapPoly']` data.

Comment: console.log gives me the object which is what the MapBox documentation says it's expecting,...and it looks correct and complete. $db['MapPoly'] is the string form. I forgot to mention,...the orginal FeatureCollection came out of MapBox orginally....and also displayed in geojsonLint. So doubtful to me that it's in the data itself.

Comment: @MichaelClark then i guess you need to look at data.always echo php variable when using in jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

ok,...I'm new here and not sure what's best to do, deleting this or not.  The solution probably isn't super helpful, except a lesson in being more careful with great big swashes of CSS.

I have a global style sheet with this line:

```
svg{width:100%;height:100%}
```

The polygons are svg. I'd like those 20 hours of screen refreshing back please.